# Error_No_Token by adding printer driver

Tags: c#, api, token

I'm trying to add printer drivers using the windows API function AddPrinterDriver. The Win32 error 1008 (An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist.) was always generated. My code is shown in following

```
[DllImport("Winspool.drv")]
static extern bool AddPrinterDriver(string Name, Int32 Level, [in] ref DRIVER_INFO_3 DriverInfo);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DRIVER_INFO_3
{
    public Int32 cVersion;
    public string Name;
    public string Environment;
    public string DriverPath;
    public string DataFile;
    public string ConfigFile;
    public string HelpFile;
    public string DependentFiles;
    public string MonitorName;
    public string DefaultDataType;
}     
//....................... 
DRIVER_INFO_3 di = new DRIVER_INFO_3();
//......................
AddPrinterDriver(Environment.MachineName, 3, ref di);
```

I have also tried to get a token by "ImpersonateSelf" before adding the printer driver. But the error 1008 insists.